# 80x86 program crashes after declaring second variable

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dosbox

I started learning assembly a few weeks ago and I wrote this program to get user input. I'm hung up because the program freezes dos box after I declare msgOut. However it will work fine if I leave it commented out along with the code to print it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
; This program gets a character from the user and prints it out 

    org 100h        ; program start point
section .data
    msgIn:  DB  "Enter a character: $"
    msgOut: DB  13, 10, "Character value: $"

section .bss
char resb 1         ; storage for input character

section .txt
; print enter message
    mov dx, msgIn   ; offset address of message to display
    mov ah, 9       ; print string function
    int 21h

; get user input
    mov ah, 1       ; keyboard input sub-program
    int 21h         ; read character into al

; store character in char variable
    mov [char], al  ; move entered char into char variable

; print second message
    mov dx, msgOut  ; offset of second message
    mov ah, 9       ; print string function
    int 21h         ; display message

; display character
    mov dl, [char]  ; char to display
    mov ah, 2       ; print char function
    int 21h

; exit program
    mov ah, 4ch     ; exit to DOS function
    int 21h         ; see you later!
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the segment registers?  I you are learning Assembly on your own, learn 32 Bit or even better - 64 bit.

Comment: Are you compiling this into a '.com' or '.exe' ?

Comment: No it is an assembly class and he is having us use nasm and dos box for 80x86. I compile with "nasm -fbin getchar.asm -o getchar.com" and then run it in dosbox. That is my complete code, so if I missed initializing something I am not aware of it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org 100h` is for a COM file.  You have your code section named `.txt`, that is wrong; it should be `.text`

```
; This program gets a character from the user and prints it out 

    org 100h        ; program start point
section .data
    msgIn:  DB  "Enter a character: $"
    msgOut: DB  13, 10, "Character value: $"

section .bss
char resb 1         ; storage for input character

section .text ; <<<<<<< notice the name!!!

; print enter message
    mov dx, msgIn   ; offset address of message to display
    mov ah, 9       ; print string function
    int 21h

; get user input
    mov ah, 1       ; keyboard input sub-program
    int 21h         ; read character into al

; store character in char variable
    mov [char], al  ; move entered char into char variable

; print second message
    mov dx, msgOut  ; offset of second message
    mov ah, 9       ; print string function
    int 21h         ; display message

; display character
    mov dl, [char]  ; char to display
    mov ah, 2       ; print char function
    int 21h

; exit program
    mov ah, 4ch     ; exit to DOS function
    int 21h         ; see you later!
```

> nasm -f bin DOSTest.asm -o DOSTest.com

[image]

@Tim, it does not matter where your data is, NASM will place the code section in the proper place

> The bin format puts the .text section first in the file, so you can
>   declare data or BSS items before beginning to write code if you want
>   to and the code will still end up at the front of the file where it
>   belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at section [8.2.1 of the nasm documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html).

I'm pretty sure you need to move your .text section to be first in the file, before the other sections. I suspect it's trying to execute your data segment, and that's why the extra variable breaks it.